# Error: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block while creating a new record

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to create a new record in a table but while creating a record below error raises.

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: Is it postgresql database?

Comment: Yep, It is a postgresql db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is, I have a field like below which I have not updated in form submit.

```
depth = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
```

this field can't be null until we make it, null=True.
So I change the above line as below and the error has been resolved.

```
depth = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```